# Facebook Security

Tags: facebook

I got a message from what was said to be Facebook Security saying something about I was being abusive or something like that and this is my last warning. I have 24 hrs to fix it (said something close to that anyway). I am totally lost as to how this could be. 
Please help me figure out what is going on.
My Facebook ID is http://www.facebook.com/#!/bwcarner

Comment: Paste the message here.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are high, that mail may be target to launch phishing attack.
Do the following:

- Check the mail headers.
- Directly log into Facebook account and check.